# Django - how to invalidate per-view cache?

Tags: django, django-cache

I want to use [per-view cache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/cache/#the-per-view-cache). I know how it's working, but where's the problem? How can I invalidate that cache? I must do it each time database records are changed. There is no info about how to do that:/

Answer (score 12):

This is a django snippet I found that might be helpful:

```
from django.core.cache import cache
from django.http import HttpRequest
from django.utils.cache import get_cache_key

def expire_page(path):
    request = HttpRequest()
    request.path = path
    key = get_cache_key(request)
    if cache.has_key(key):   
        cache.delete(key)
```

Otherwise this SO question goes into more detail regarding this: [Expire a view-cache in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268417/expire-a-view-cache-in-django)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this snippet http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/936/. Pass the path(url) of the view to the expire_page function function, every time you want to invalidate the cache.

Comment: As url, should I pass a result of reverse function? I pass that: expire_page(reverse('index_show_freelinks', kwargs={'name':'partners'})) but cache is still valid.

Comment: Are you sure that `reverse` is returning the URL you want? Maybe try just hardcoding it to see if it works. How are you testing if the cache is still valid?