# Django Cache cache.set Not storing data

Tags: python, django, caching, memcached, django-cache

When I run `python manage.py shell` and then:

```py
from django.core.cache import cache
cache.set("stack","overflow",3000)
print cache.get("stack")
    
(output: ) None
```

I tried restarting memcache, and here is what's in my settings:

```
CACHES = { 
  'default' : { 
     'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache', 
     'LOCATION' : '127.0.0.1:11211',
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have one of python-memcached or pylibmc installed?

Comment: Yeah, I have python-memcached installed

Comment: Have you verified that the port 11211 is open?

Comment: also you should try running memcached with the -vv flag to get "very verbose" output to see if there any issues

Comment: Do you have other cache specific settings in settings.py?

Comment: Isn't that you are serving it on a virtualenv?

Comment: This is a silly question, but are you doing cache.get('stack') quickly enough?  Try just cache.set('stack', 'overflow') and then using cache.get('stack').

Comment: Are you sure your memcached is up? Did you try to set and get a cache key [using telnet](http://www.lzone.de/cheat-sheet/memcached)?

Comment: I would recommend installing [django-debug-toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar). Once it is installed and added to your DJANGO_APPS. you will see a sidebar on your page. Open the sidebar and check the cache option to see if the cache has really been set.

Comment: try to use a `'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache` as default cache then if the code works try to change the cache backend with memcache.

Comment: Worked for me in a virtualenv with a brand new memcached system install. The only settings I am using beside what you listed are CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ALIAS = "default", CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS = 7200, CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX = "".

Comment: Do you set DEBUG = True ? (Maybe you have this in your settings.py and memcached is looking for)

Answer (score 3):

Make sure it's using the correct cache. Try `from django.core.cache import caches`, and then see the contents of `caches.all()`. It should just have one instance of `django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache`.
If it is, try accessing that directly, e.g.

```
from django.core.cache import caches  
m_cache = caches.all()[0]
m_cache.set("stack","overflow",3000)
m_cache.get("stack")
```

This might not solve your problem, but will at least get you closer to debugging Memcached instead of Django's cache proxy or your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I believe django augments the key with a version. For example,

```
django_memcache.set('my_key', 'django', 1000)
```

will set the key `:1:my_key` in memcache:

```
<36 set :1:my_key 0 1000 6
>36 STORED
```

However, if you set the key through telnet or python-memcached module, it will store the raw key as expected:

```
<38 set my_key 0 1000 13 
>38 STORED
```

So, perhaps you are not querying the correct key?

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/cache/#cache-key-transformation

Answer (score -1):

With [set()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/cache/#django.core.cache.cache.set), [set_many()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/cache/#django.core.cache.cache.set_many), [get()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/cache/#django.core.cache.cache.get), [get_many()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/cache/#django.core.cache.cache.get_many) and [get_or_set()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/cache/#django.core.cache.cache.get_or_set), you can set and get cache values with [LocMemCache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/cache/#local-memory-caching) which is used by default as shown below. *`set()` can set a timeout and a version and `set_many()` can set multiple cache values with a timeout and `get()` can get the key's cache value matched with the version and get a default value if the key doesn't exist and `get_many()` can get multiple cache values and `get_or_set()` can get a key's cache value if the key exists or set and get a key's cache value if the key doesn't exist and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784400/clearing-specific-cache-in-django/76941811#76941811) explains how to delete cache values with `LocMemCache` and [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76936038/does-cache-set-use-version-1-by-default-instead-of-version-none-in-djang#76936070) of [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76936038/does-cache-set-use-version-1-by-default-instead-of-version-none-in-djang) explains the default version of a cache value with `LocMemCache`:

```py
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.core.cache import cache

def test(request):
    cache.set("first_name", "John")
    cache.set("first_name", "David", 30, 2)
    cache.set("last_name", "Smith")
    cache.set("last_name", "Miller", version=2)
    cache.set_many({"age": 36, "gender": "Male"}, 50)

    print(cache.get("first_name")) # John
    print(cache.get("first_name", version=2)) # David
    print(cache.get("first_name", "Doesn't exist", version=3)) # Doesn't exist
    print(cache.get_many(["first_name", "last_name", "age", "gender"]))
    # {'first_name': 'John', 'last_name': 'Smith', 'age': 36, 'gender': 'Male'}
    print(cache.get_many(["first_name", "last_name", "age", "gender"], 2))
    # {'first_name': 'David', 'last_name': 'Miller'}
    print(cache.get_or_set("first_name", "Doesn't exist")) # John
    print(cache.get_or_set("email", "Doesn't exist")) # Doesn't exist
    return HttpResponse("Test")
```