# Does `cache.set()` use `version=1` by default instead of `version=None` in Django?

Tags: python, django, caching, version, django-cache

If I only set and get `David` with `version=0`, then I can get `John` and `David` in order as shown below. *I use [LocMemCache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/cache/#local-memory-caching) which is the default cache in Django and I'm learning [Django Cache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/cache/):

```py
from django.core.cache import cache

cache.set("name", "John")
cache.set("name", "David", version=0)
print(cache.get("name")) # John
print(cache.get("name", version=0)) # David
```

And, if I only set and get `David` with `version=2`, then I can get `John` and `David` in order as well as shown below:

```py
from django.core.cache import cache

cache.set("name", "John")
cache.set("name", "David", version=2)
print(cache.get("name")) # John
print(cache.get("name", version=2)) # David
```

But, if I only set and get `David` with `version=1`, then I can get `David` and `David` in order as shown below so this is because `John` is set with `version=1` by default?:

```py
from django.core.cache import cache

cache.set("name", "John")
cache.set("name", "David", version=1)
print(cache.get("name")) # David
print(cache.get("name", version=1)) # David
```

In addition, if I set and get `John` and `David` without `version=1`, then I can get `David` and `David` in order as well as shown below:

```py
from django.core.cache import cache

cache.set("name", "John")
cache.set("name", "David")
print(cache.get("name")) # David
print(cache.get("name")) # David
```

I know that [the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/cache/#django.core.cache.cache.set) shows `version=None` for `cache.set()` as shown below:

```py
                                               ↓ ↓ Here ↓ ↓
cache.set(key, value, timeout=DEFAULT_TIMEOUT, version=None)
```

So, does `cache.set()` actually use `version=1` by default instead of `version=None` in Django?

Answer (score 2):

> So, does `cache.set()` actually use `version=1` by default instead of version=None in Django?

It uses the version specified in the cache. Indeed, if we look at the [source code <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/django/django/blob/517d3bb4dd17e9c51690c98d747b86a0ed8b2fbf/django/core/cache/backends/base.py#L98-L109), we see:

> ```
> def make_key(self, key, version=None):
>     """
>     Construct the key used by all other methods. By default, use the
>     key_func to generate a key (which, by default, prepends the
>     `key_prefix' and 'version'). A different key function can be provided
>     at the time of cache construction; alternatively, you can subclass the
>     cache backend to provide custom key making behavior.
>     """
>     if version is None:
>         version = self.version
>
>     return self.key_func(key, self.key_prefix, version)
> ```

and the [`version` can be set as parameter, or will default to one <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/django/django/blob/517d3bb4dd17e9c51690c98d747b86a0ed8b2fbf/django/core/cache/backends/base.py#L60-L84):

> ```
> def __init__(self, params):
>     # …
>     self.version = params.get("VERSION", 1)
>     # …
> ```

so you can set this in the cache settings with:

```
CACHES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache",
        "LOCATION": "unique-snowflake",
        "VERSION": 1425,
    }
}
```

if not, it will indeed default to one. This is also (briefly) explained in the options for the cache in [the documentation on settings <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#std-setting-CACHES-VERSION):

> **VERSION**
>
> Default: `1`
>
> The default version number for cache keys generated by the Django server.

Answer (score 0):

In the official documentation ([part about cache versioning](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/cache/#cache-versioning)) write "...By default, any key request will automatically include the site **default cache key version**..."
And in [this place of documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#version) we can see than this default cache key version = **1** by default