# Django caching - purge cache

Tags: django, caching

I want a simple behaviour from the caching mechanism, but I can't find a way to obtain it. I'd be fine with per-site or per-view caching, but I want some sort of control on when to *invalidate* cache.

For example, imagine that I have the simplest kind of site, a blog. Until I submit a new post, the frontpage doesn't change, so I'm ok with the HTML to be cached for days, but I'd like a way to say "refresh the cache *now*" whenever I submit a new post, so that the first call to my site after the new submission doesn't use the cached HTML but produces a new page that is going to be used till my next blog post.

How to do this? Thanks

**EDIT**:

`cache.clear()` works well and as expected, but I'd like a more "specific" option where I can specify what view to expire, not the whole cache. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2363690/931277) will work.  There is some more in depth explanation in that thread as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a look at advanced caching solutions like [cacheops](https://github.com/Suor/django-cacheops) or [cache-machine](https://github.com/jbalogh/django-cache-machine). These will handle invalidation for you.