# Django partially caching a view

Tags: django, caching, django-templates

I have a simple page with the parts:

- a list of items taken from the database
- a header.

On the header lies the usual "login form" or the name of signed-in user. For all the users the "items part" is the same, but if I cache the whole view, the different header (your own username or login form if you're not signed-in) is not shown according to the user state. How can I cache the "items" part and leave the header dynamic? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [template fragment cache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#template-fragment-caching). It allows you to cache only a fragment of a template with your item list:

```
{% load cache %}
 A header here
{% cache 500  %}
   List of items here
{% endcache %}
```

Comment: thanks, this works as expected. how can I force expire on this? like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9350794/django-caching-purge-cache but fragment-based?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Django's cache system and version 1.3, it looks like this is very easy with [template fragment caching](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/cache/#template-fragment-caching). In fact, the version given in the docs suggests caching both parts of the page as separate fragments, keying the header to the logged-in user:

```
{% load cache %}

{% cache 500 header request.user.username %}
    .. header ..
{% endcache %}

{% cache 500 items %}
    .. items ..
{% endcache %}
```