# Expiring a view-cache in Django 1.3.1

Tags: python, django, caching, django-views

I'm trying to expire a view-level cache on a model's `post_save` (that was set via https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/cache/?from=olddocs#the-per-view-cache). I did some googling and found this answer here on SO: [Expire a view-cache in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268417/expire-a-view-cache-in-django) but it's not working for me.

I asked around in the #django room on freenode and the consensus was that this was probably due to [the recent caching changes made in 1.3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/releases/1.3/#caching-changes)

Does anyone have any idea on how I can wipe out the cache entry for a model keyed off it's `get_absolute_url()`?

Comment: If [ilvar's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10458883/296974) is close enough to your solution, accept it. Otherwise, post an own answer and accept that as soon as you can and at least upvote ilvar's answer if it was helpful.

Comment: OK, thanks @glglgl...still learning how things work here. :) I just moved my solution out of the body of the question and into it's own answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### I figured it out!

Cheers to [ilvar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1215136/ilvar) for pointing me in the right direction. My implementation is below. I created a property named `cache_key` and added a post_save receiver onto the sub class of the models whose view-level caches I needed to clear after they had been updated. Suggestions for improvement are always welcome!

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.cache import cache
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.http import HttpRequest
from django.utils.cache import _generate_cache_header_key

from someapp.models import BaseModelofThisClass

class SomeModel(BaseModelofThisClass):
    ...
    @property
    def cache_key(self):
        # Create a fake request object
        request = HttpRequest()
        # Set the request method
        request.method = "GET"
        # Set the request path to be this object's permalink.
        request.path = self.get_absolute_url()
        # Grab the key prefix (if it exists) from settings
        key_prefix = settings.CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX
        # Generate this object's cache key using django's key generator
        key = _generate_cache_header_key(key_prefix, request)
        # This is a bit hacky but necessary as I don't know how to do it
        # properly otherwise. While generating a cache header key, django
        # uses the language of the HttpRequest() object as part of the
        # string. The fake request object, by default, uses
        # settings.LANGUAGE_CODE as it's language (in my case, 'en-us')
        # while the true request objects that are used in building views
        # use settings.LANGUAGES ('en'). Instead of replacing the segment
        # of the string after the fact it would be far better create a more
        # closely mirrored HttpRequest() object prior to passing it to
        # _generate_cache_header_key().
        key = key.replace(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE, settings.LANGUAGES[settings.DEFAULT_LANGUAGE][0])

        return key

    @receiver(post_save)
    def clear_cache_for_this_item(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        # If this is a sub-class of another model
        if sender not in BaseModelofThisClass.__subclasses__():
            return
        else:
            cache.delete(instance.cache_key)
```

Answer (score 3):

Django's caching middleware is using [this](https://github.com/django/django/blob/e84f79f05113f546810c1908c7baef99fb1e874a/django/utils/cache.py#L176) to generate a cache key for the request. So, you can make a fake `request` with desired path and get a cache key. Then simply delete it from the cache.

P.S. `cache_page` decorator also uses that middlewares so it should work the same way.