# Explicitly clear django memcached flush/cache() OR delete specific per-view-cache key

Tags: django, caching, memcached, flush

I'm using django's Memcached and the per-view caching mechanism with the `@cache_page(timeout)` decorator.

Inside a particular view function I wish to clear the entire cache.
I tried `cache.clear()` and `cache._cache.flush_all()` but neither seem to flush the cache.

Is there some other way to do this or am I doing it wrong?

EDIT:
I realize that completely clearing the cache is not such a good idea as opposed to just deleting the required keys. However, I do not know the keys for the views I've decorated with @cache_page(timeout) How do I get to know these? And after I acquire the key, I just do a cache.delete(key)?

Thanks!

Comment: There's really not a good reason ever to clear the *entire* cache. Just remove the keys you want to refresh, and don't mess with the rest of it.

Comment: I do not know the keys for the views I've decorated with @cache_page(timeout)

How do I get to know these?
And after I acquire the key, I just do a cache.delete(key)?

Comment: Check out this related SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268417/expire-a-view-cache-in-django

Answer (score 1):

There is be a better way than flushing the entire cache. See [cache versioning](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/?from=olddocs#cache-versioning):

> When you change running code that uses cached values, you may need to
>   purge any existing cached values. The easiest way to do this is to
>   flush the entire cache, but this can lead to the loss of cache values
>   that are still valid and useful.
>
> Django provides a better way to target individual cache values.
>   Django's cache framework has a system-wide version identifier,
>   specified using the VERSION cache setting. The value of this setting
>   is automatically combined with the cache prefix and the user-provided
>   cache key to obtain the final cache key.