# How update django cache in exact time?

Tags: python, django

On my site, there are several pages that make a large sample from the database, but updating them enough times a day, preferably at night. How to do it right?

I have already enable cache, the issue is to update it at a certain time.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set proper cache expire date? That should solve the problem.

**EDIT:**

Maybe the answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268417/expire-a-view-cache-in-django)?

Comment: 'TIMEOUT' in settings.py? Yes now it's 86400, but I think it's not good, it can slide.

Comment: Hm, I was thinking about `cache.set('my_key', 'hello, world!', 30)` - 30 is the cache time. [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/cache/#basic-usage)

Comment: How do you cache them? Using the low-level cache API?