# How not to generate the same dynamic image twice in Python, Django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I have a view that returns a generated image. I use the view twice: to show an image on page with some other stuff and to show the image in separate window when clicking on the image. But since generation of an image takes quite a while I would like to somehow escape the nessecity to repeat myself.

**views.py**

```
# named 'dynamic-image' in urls.py
def dynamic_image(request, graph_name):
    # generate the image (always the same for our case)
    return HttpResponse(image, content_type="image/svg+xml")

def index(request):
    template_name = 'graphs/index.html'
    ...
    return render(request,template_name,{})
```

**index.html**

```
<a href = "{% url 'dynamic-image' simplified_cell_states_graph %}">
    <img src="{% url 'dynamic-image' simplified_cell_states_graph %}" alt="img3">
</a>
```

I wish I could reuse the image, generated for index template, by showing it in a separate window and then just forget about the image.

**upd** added cache_page as suggested

```
@cache_page(60 * 15)
def dynamic_image(request, graph_name):
    # generate the image (always the same for our case)
    return HttpResponse(image, content_type="image/svg+xml")
```

**upd** How to uncache page? `cache.delete(key)` does not clear cache for me. Here is the test demonstrating it:

```
from django.utils.cache import get_cache_key
from django.core.cache import cache

def test_cache_invalidation_with_cache(self):
    self.factory = RequestFactory()        
    url = reverse('dynamic-image', args=('simplified_cell_states_graph',))
    request = self.factory.get(url)
    response = self.client.get(url)
    cache_key = get_cache_key(request)
    self.assertFalse(cache_key == None) #key found

    cache.delete(cache_key) # but no deletion

    cache_key = get_cache_key(request)
    self.assertEquals(cache_key, None) # fails here
```

Comment: You don't want to generate the image again when you click on it?

Comment: Yes. And I don't want to store it on server either. But I will if it is the only option.

Comment: Is it the same image? The same size? There are multiple ways to do this. One, you can use JS and not send another server request. You can also take a look at Django's cached framework and invalidate the cache once you're done: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/cache/ There are other ways as well but I'd start here to see if this is what you need.

Comment: caching is what I need.

Comment: Great! Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [cached view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/cache/#the-per-view-cache):

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page

@cache_page(60 * 15)
def dynamic_image(request, graph_name):
    ...
```

Comment: This looks cool and way more simple than I thought. And how do I `uncache_page` manualy (not after 15 minutes)?

Comment: You can get the key for you view using `get_cache_key()` method.  Cached view result can be deleted with `cache.delete(key)`.  See the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/utils/#django.utils.cache.get_cache_key

Comment: Look at the answer for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268417/expire-a-view-cache-in-django

Comment: To check the value of the cached view you should use `cache.get(key)` instead of `get_cache_key(request)`.