# Caching a ViewSet with DRF : TypeError: _wrapped_view()

Tags: django, caching, django-rest-framework, memcached

I just want to use caching to a ViewSet too slow :(, with Django REST Framework.

I've do this :

```
...
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page
from django.views.decorators.vary import vary_on_cookie
...
class PRPKViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = PrpkSerializer
    queryset = Prpk.objects.all().order_by('begin')
    # Authentification !
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    # Only 'get' method
    http_method_names = ['get']

    # Cache requested url for each user for 2 hours
    # @method_decorator(vary_on_cookie)
    @method_decorator(cache_page(60*2))
    def get_queryset(self):
        """ allow rest api to filter by submissions """
        queryset = Prpk.objects.all().order_by('begin')
        highway = self.request.query_params.get('highway', None)
        if highway is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(highway=highway)

        return queryset
```

But when querying, I've this error :

```
TypeError: _wrapped_view() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'
```

Memcached is installed.

So, can I caching just one ViewSet (not using an extension ?) ?

Thanks a lot.

F.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Decorate `dispatch` instead of `get_queryset`.

```
@method_decorator(cache_page(60*2))
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I've just add the "dispatch" function above "get_queryset" but I've this error :   "if response.streaming or response.status_code not in (200, 304):AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'streaming'"

Comment: my bad : missing "return" :). First query : 11 s, second call : 431 ms :). It's working. For now, how can I see the pages currently cached, please ?

Comment: @fabrice true, I missed `return`, fixed. Look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9048257/get-list-of-cache-keys-in-django to see how to get chached pages, as that's a different question.

Comment: How do you invalidate `cache_page` ? and test if its really working

Comment: IMPORTANT NOTE: If you have authentication on your viewset then the cache check will be done before auth check which is really dangerous.

Comment: @RyanAquino invalidating it is a bit tricky, discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33749369/how-to-invalidate-cache-page-in-django
and also here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268417/expire-a-view-cache-in-django?noredirect=1&lq=1