# Django cache_page with keys

Tags: django

What I am trying to achieve is set a cache_page on a certain class-based view and when a user saves a certain model,, the cache in the page is supposed to be deleted. I tried using:

```
cache_page(60*1, key_prefix='artists')
```

then declaring this on the models.py

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    from django.core.cache import cache
    cache.delete('artists')
    super(Artist, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**However it did not work.**

I tried using:

```
cache.clear()
```

on the custom save method(the same line as cache.delete()) And it worked.. But what I want is just deleting a certain cache not everything that is why .clear() is not acceptable

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36845722/3570352 - this answer contains version updated for Django 1.7+ (tested on 1.9)