# Uncaching the results of a particular view in django

Tags: django, caching, django-views, django-cache

I have come across [this project](https://syfou.bitbucket.io/django-groupcache/overview.html). It uncaches the results of a particular view in django. I want to do a similar thing but I read that this project is no longer updated. I am using Memcached and Django 1.8. I want to delete all the cache entries of a particular view whenever I make changes to the databases. Earlier I was clearing the entire cache whenever a new object was added, but I think its better to just clear the entries of concerned view. Is there someway to do it using the cache_control decorator or some other effective way?

Comment: Chances are that your site does not need any sort of caching whatsoever

Comment: It has a few images so I think caching will be useful

Comment: Images are usually cached using http header instructions, which tells the browser to cache images client side. This is configured in nginx a CDN, or however you serve your image files. Django caching is server side, and useful for sites with many visitors and expensive template rendering. A news portal front page is a good example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expire a view-cache in Django?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268417/expire-a-view-cache-in-django)