# how can i invalidate page cache in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-caching

How can I invalidate page cache in django.
I am trying to cache a page displays a list that is unique for each user using django-rest-framework. I can not figure out how to invalidate the page cache when the another object is added, updated, deleted from the model.

I am open to using an external package or signals.

I don't know what the key is for @page_cache to invalidate the cache

I have tried to use django-fancy-cache but I just get an error

```
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'function'
```

my cache settings

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
         'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
         'LOCATION': 'unique-snowflake',
     }
}
```

Comment: Why cache a page that is unique for each user?

Comment: the same user may view this page multiple times per minute. and the page is very processor heavy

Answer (score 1):

You can move your invalidation logic to your models. For example, in order to invalidate a cache when an object is added/updated, you can override model's save method. e.g:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    cache.delete(`YOUR_CACHE_KEY`)
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

same for delete:

```
def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
    cache.delete(`YOUR_CACHE_KEY`)
    super().delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I know that I can delete the cache. the problem is that I don't know what the cache key is for the page

Comment: @user14665310 I think this link might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268417/expire-a-view-cache-in-django/36845722#36845722

Comment: Thank you that answer did not help but a different answer did work https://stackoverflow.com/a/7455114/14665310