# django 3.0.2 get_cache_key returns different cache keys

Tags: python, django, caching, django-cache, redis-cache

I'm trying to invalidate a view following this [Expire a view-cache in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268417/expire-a-view-cache-in-django).

Here's a view function where I have disabled `per-site` caching and enabled `per-view` caching.

This is the view, say, that I need to **invalidate**.

```
@api_view(["GET"])
@never_cache
@cache_page(60*60)
def get_segment_list(request, appid: str, page: str) -> JsonResponse:
    try:
    ...
```

I have already called `get_segment_list` once and that has cached the response header and page.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> keys *
1) ":1:views.decorators.cache.cache_page..GET.39679326f007515994e08d99042c26f7.d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e.en-us.UTC"
2) ":1:views.decorators.cache.cache_header..39679326f007515994e08d99042c26f7.en-us.UTC". <<-- NOTE THIS
```

Here's a `expire-view` function.

```
def expire_view_cache(view_name, args=[], namespace=None, key_prefix=None):
    """
    This function allows you to invalidate any view-level cache.
        view_name: view function you wish to invalidate or it's named url pattern
        args: any arguments passed to the view function
        namepace: optional, if an application namespace is needed
        key prefix: for the @cache_page decorator for the function (if any)
    """
    from django.urls import reverse
    from django.http import HttpRequest
    from django.utils.cache import get_cache_key
    from django.core.cache import cache
    # create a fake request object
    request = HttpRequest()

    # lookup the request path:
    if namespace:
        view_name = namespace + ":" + view_name

    request.META = {
        'SERVER_NAME': '1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa',
        'SERVER_PORT': 8000,
    }
    request.LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
    request.path = reverse(view_name, kwargs=args)
    # get cache key, expire if the cached item exists:
    key = get_cache_key(request, method='GET', key_prefix=key_prefix)
    if key:
        if cache.get(key):
            # Delete the cache entry.
            cache.set(key, None, 0)
        return True
    return False
```

`request.META` details are copied from the previous `request` object while caching `get_segment_list`.

But in `expire_view_cache` a different `cache_header` key is generated.

```
'views.decorators.cache.cache_header..9a20b800712b08ba816e521ea6b8081d.en-us.UTC'
```

This could probably be due to different `request` headers but I am clueless as to what is missing from the fake request.

Any help is appreciated.